# Inaccuracy in output of deletion function in binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, binary-search-tree

I am making a binary search tree code, in that 'am facing an issue in the deletion function. After executing the function, the code is showing inorder display incorrectly. Basically, it is incorrect, and I'am not able to understand where the problem is.

In the delete function, I have used a search function that will find the node which the user has to delete. And I have used inorder successor method for deletion so the minimum function will find the successor. All other functions like insertion, minimum, and inorder are working fine.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
    } node;
    struct node *insert(struct node *tnode, int data)
    {
    if (tnode == NULL)
    {
        struct node *ptr;
        ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ptr->data = data;
        ptr->left = NULL;
        ptr->right = NULL;
        return ptr;
    }
    if (data > (tnode->data))
    {
        tnode->right = insert(tnode->right, data);
        return tnode;
    }
    if (data < (tnode->data))
    {
        tnode->left = insert(tnode->left, data);
        return tnode;
    }
    }
    void in_order(struct node *tnode)
    {
    if (tnode == NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        in_order(tnode->left);
        printf("%d\t", tnode->data);
        in_order(tnode->right);
    }
    }
    struct node *search(struct node *tnode, int data)
    {
    if (tnode == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (data == tnode->data)
        {
            return tnode;
        }
        else
        {
            if (data > tnode->data)
            {
                search(tnode->right, data);
            }
            else
            {
                search(tnode->left, data);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    struct node *minimum(struct node *tnode)
    {
    if (tnode == NULL)
    {
        printf("No node present\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (tnode->left == NULL)
            return tnode;
        else
            minimum(tnode->left);
    }
    }
    struct node *deletenode(struct node *tnode, int data)
    {
    struct node *s;
    s = search(tnode, data);
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        printf("Value not found\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if (s->left == NULL && s->right == NULL) // No child case
        {
            free(s);
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            if (s->left == NULL && s->right != NULL) // single child case(right child)
            {
                struct node *temp = s->right;
                free(s);
                return temp;
            }
            else if (s->right == NULL && s->left != NULL) // single child case(left child)
            {
                struct node *temp = s->left;
                free(s);
                return temp;
            }
            else
            {
                struct node *temp;
                temp = minimum(s->right);
                s->data = temp->data;
                s->right = deletenode(s->right, temp->data);
            }
        }
    }

    return s;
    }
    int main()
    {
    struct node *root = NULL, *del;
    int n, i, data, key;
    printf("Enter how many nodes you have to enter in a tree\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter data\n");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        root = insert(root, data);
    }
    printf("\nIN-Order display\n");
    in_order(root);
    int d;
    printf("\nEnter data to be delete\n");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    del=deletenode(root, d);
    printf("\nIN-Order display\n");
    in_order(root);
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several places missing `return` (in `minimum`, `search` and `deletenode`). You can easily find them if you compile with `-Wall -Wextra` compiler options.

It is not clear, what do you want to return from `deletenode`. I assume that it is a tree with deleted element. Then either `search` should return a parent node (so it is possible to change pointers to freed node), or `deletenode` should move to parent node.

Also, use `in_order(del)` instead of `in_order(root)` because root can be changed while deleting.

Comment: could you please specify that on which line in functions **search**, **minimum** and **deletenode**  **return** is missing. And I want to return deleted node from **deletenode** function. Basically, I want that **search** function search the node of given data and **deletenode** function delete that node from tree. And **in_order** function should show the updated tree. I have tried **in_order(del)** instead of **in_order(root)** but the result is same(it is only showing values  till that deleted node only, in inorder)

Comment: Lines 58,62,79 should have return. 

You shouldn't return deleted node - it is deleted, isn't it? You have freed memory, there is no node left. 

If you want to update tree, then you should find a parent node, and modify its children.